# App does not have access to all the data in JSON Store

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am facing an issue in the Work Execution application where the page size on the resource is defined as 1000 and it loads just 1000 into the app cache

This is OK from a performance point of view, but if I am trying to search [using the search bar on top] for data it should go look for it in the whole data set and not just that 1000

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see from the email you sent me that the resource you're attempting to search is the Location resource, and you're trying to search the location resource within the Location lookup.  The issue where only the first page of data was being searched was fixed under this APAR IV83948, and is available out of the box in 7.6.1 or from an iFix on 7.6

Comment: I have the same issue with the Service Address lookup as well. Is that also addressed in that iFix?